# What is the proper way to use an external USB disk for Time Machine?

Tags: time-machine, usb

New-to-me Macbook pro 2019 2-USB3 ports. Installed powered USB hub to connect to the world, including a USB thumb drive for Time Machine. The backup process works fine.

Upon wake-up every morning, I'm greeted with "The Disk was not ejected properly." But of course it hasn't been ejected At All.

In Windows, there's a switch to disallow write-behind caching on USB devices which, when set, allows a USB device to be yanked from the port at will with no complaint from the OS.

How do I engage such similar behavior on this beast? What's the fix?

--edited to add-- Well, like most things, there's more to this than meets the eye. I had installed an unpowered multi-connect whizbang device to give me HDMI, memory card, USB-A and -C connects, and from on of the USB-A chained a powered multi-outlet USB-A hub. It was into this powered hub that I had connected the Time_Machine thumb drive, and one more for ease of file transfer to another laptop. Both of these thumb drives threw the dismount error when they were attached to the powered hub. Now the good part. Neither of them complain when one of them is connected to the first hub in the string of two...so the problem is interestinger and interestinger, as Alice has said. Point being that the error no longer occurs, so this thread is done. Cheers, all and thanks for the warning about the frailty of thumb drives in general.
-30-

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, macOS automatically tries to put hard disks to sleep when the computer goes to sleep. Try going to Energy Saver Preferences and unchecking the option to put hard disks to sleep whenever possible.

Comment: Your current issue aside - I would most definitely not entrust a Time Machine backup to any kind of 'thumb drive' They have *spectacularly* high fail rates & will go from working to completely dead at little more prompting than your current 'not ejected properly' problem.

Comment: What @Tetsujin said.  Plus,  try a proper USB drive (not a thumb drive) as they have the ability to sleep where as a thumb drive doesn’t..